# Rails 3.2 Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

In my first approach with Rails I have simply create a void `SayController` and static `hello.rhtml` view but when the page `http://localhost:3000/say/hello` started return me a Routing Error like this:

```
No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Rails version: 3.2.6

Comment: So, what was the output from "rake routes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have something in your `config/routes.rb` to define that route. Try:

```
match 'say/hello' => 'say#hello', :as => 'say_hello'
```

The go to `localhost:3000/say/hello`
Also check out this documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: it work, fine!
but I don't understand if it's a task to run every time I create a controller?

Comment: If you create a new method in controller and want to route to it, you have to define that in the config/routes.rb.

Comment: Now i have Template Missing error:
Missing template say/hello, application/hello with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/rails_proj/demo/app/views"

Comment: This is how Model View Controller in Rails works. You have a controller Say with an action Hello, now you need a View Hello that is inside Say. The app looks into app/views/application/ or app/views/say/ for something like hello.html.erb to display on the web. Try creating such html file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't add a [route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for `hello` to your `config/routes.rb` file.

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'say/hello' => 'say#hello', :as => :hello
end
```

This will match route `say/hello` to controller `say` (the part before `#`) and action `hello` (the part after `#`).

`:as => :hello` makes it a [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) so you can refer to it as `hello_path` from within your app.

The error message tells you to run `rake routes` (from the console) which will show you the [existing routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake) in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, controller: **say** and action: **hello**

Add following to config/route.rb

```
 get 'say/hello' => 'Say#hello'
```